# How to show that these two constructions of Tychonoff product topology are equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

**Definition:** The Tychonoff product topology on $X = \Pi_{t \in T}X_t$, is the topology $\tau$, which is generated by the family

> $\bigcup\{ p_t^{-1}(\tau(X_t)) : t \in T \}$ as a subbase

where $\tau(X_t)$ is the family of open sets in $X_t$, and $p_t:X \rightarrow X_t$ is the projection map.

Does anyone know how to prove that the set:

> $\mathcal B = \{ \Pi_{t \in T} U_t : U_t \in \tau (X_t) \text{ for all }
> > t,\text{ and  the  set } \{ t \in T : U_t \neq X_t \} \text{ is  finite}\}$

Is a base for the space $X = \Pi_{t \in T}X_t$ ?

I must admit, I have allways thought that the topology on $X = \Pi_{t \in T}X_t$ is defined to be the one which is generated by $\mathcal B$ as a base. I didn't know, that I was actually using an equivalent definition which should first be proved.

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the finite intersections of sets of the form $p_t^{-1}(U_t)$, where $U_t$ is open in $X_t$?

Comment: mm.. are you suggesting that it is exactly the sets in $\mathcal B$? Is it that simple?

Comment: Yes, exactly those.

Comment: I see. ok. Thank you!!

Comment: @GeneralTopology The significance of the first definition is that it makes it more obvious that the product topology is the *initial* topology regarding the family of projections $p_t$. Whenever you have a set $X$ and some family of projections $p_i \,:\, X \to U_i$, where all $U_i$ are topological spaces, you can find the coarsest topology on $X$ that makes all the projections continuous. That topology is called the *initial* topology on $X$, and the product topology is an example of such an initial topology.